# Get Python Shell open

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i open Python 3.7.3 and all i get is a black window that looks like the command prompt window. Where is the shell? Where do I write my code? I saw an example with this same version of python where there were 2 white windows, one with the code and the other being the shell but i am confused how to set that up.

Is there a difference between just python 3.7.3 and IDLE? As you can see I am basically lost in this whole situation.

The window that I see looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMXwd.jpg

Comment: You are looking for a text editor or an IDE, Python itself is an interpreter: write your code in a `.py` file and run it with Python `python my_code.py`

Comment: @Silveris okay but what is the thing I saw with the 2 windows, 1 the shell and the other the code?

Comment: Several IDEs can do it, such as PyCharm or VS code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, to name the basic ones:

1. Write your python code as a plain text file with an editor of your choice, and execute using:

`python myfile.py`

2. Write your python code in a simple IDE (e.g. sublime, atom) that has fancy features such as auto-indentation and colour coding, and execute using:

`python myfile.py`

3. Write your code in a fancy IDE that allows you to have shell and code at the same time, and execute within the IDE (e.g. PyCharm)

Answer (score 0):

That's the python shell where you can issue python commands. You can call a python script as stated above and even code python directly in that window. Here is an example:

1. Type `from secrets import token_urlsafe` and hit return. Now you've imported your first python module.
2. Type `ran_num = token_urlsafe(16)` and hit return. Now we've declared a variable called ran_num and gave it the value of 16 random number, letters, and characters.
3. Type `print(ran_num)` and look at the output, which should be something like this - `W2Z6O4XGebDa-eXbJY5p3Q`

This is just one example. There are a lot of uses.